# Laravel 5.6 Custom Query Build showing empty result

Tags: laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

No errors, just an empty result. I am trying to work out why this query within a model is showing an empty collection.

Mysql Workbench query:

```
select
    u.`name`, u.email, ual.admin, a.account_name
from
    users as u
    join users_account_link as ual on u.id = ual.user_id and u.account_id_in_use = ual.account_id
    join accounts a on ual.account_id = a.id
where
    u.sub = 'ABCDE';
```

Spits one row containing the desired result set.

Recreating this in Laravel query builder:

```
$settings = DB::table('users as u')
            ->join('users_account_link as ual', function ($join) {
                  $join->on('u.id', '=', 'ual.user_id')
                       ->where('u.account_id_in_use', '=', 'ual.account_id');
                  })
            ->join('accounts as a', 'ual.account_id', '=', 'a.id')
            ->select('u.name as user_name', 'u.email as user_email', 'ual.admin as admin_check', 'a.account_name')
            ->where('u.sub',auth()->user()->sub)
            ->get();

dd($settings);
```

Provides an empty collection. I have done many custom queries which work well however the problem I have narrowed down the result set is the additional condition for `join users_account_link as ual on u.id = ual.user_id and u.account_id_in_use = ual.account_id` and have tried to move this condition to a where clause which still provides an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

`'u.account_id_in_use', '=', 'ual.account_id'` are both integers however replacing u.account_id_in_use with a hardcoded integer e.g. 2 would return a result. Therefore, Laravel seems to have an issue with this field and replaced the where-> with a whereRaw now returns the desired result.

For anyone having a similar issue, try replacing fields with hardcode values to isolate the issue and look into using raw when possible to overcome the issue.

Hope this helps anyone in need.